# XSLT - add attributes to result elements - xml to html transformtion

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing a xml to html conversion using xslt. My input xml is follows,

```
<doc>
    <h1>main header 1-1</h1>
    <p>para 1</p>
    <p>para 2</p>

    <h1>main header 1-2</h1>
    <p>para 3</p>
    <p>para 4</p>
    <h2>sub header 2-1</h2>
    <p>para 5</p>
    <p>para 6</p>
    <p>para 7</p>
    <h2>sub header 2-3</h2>
    <p>para 8</p>
    <p>para 9</p>

    <h1>main header 1-3</h1>
    <p>para 10</p>
    <h2>sub header 2-3</h2>
    <p>para 11</p>
    <p>para 12</p>
</doc>
```

I need to create menu using above xml data. and I've already written the css for the menu.

My desired html output code from above xml is follows,

```
<doc>
    <div name="list">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="h1-1">main header 1-1</a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="h1-2">main header 1-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='last'><a href="h2-1">sub header 2-1</a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href="h2-2">sub header 2-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href="h1-3">main header 1-3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='last'><a href="h2-3">sub header 2-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">

        <div id="h1-1">
            <h1>main header 1-1</h1>
            <p>para 1</p>
            <p>para 2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="h1-2">
            <h1>main header 1-2</h1>
            <p>para 3</p>
            <p>para 4</p>
            <div id="h2-1">
                <h2>sub header 2-1</h2>
                <p>para 5</p>
                <p>para 6</p>
                <p>para 7</p>
            </div>
            <div id="h2-2">
                <h2>sub header 2-3</h2>
                <p>para 8</p>
                <p>para 9</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="h1-3">
            <h1>main header 1-3</h1>
            <p>para 10</p>
            <div id="h2-3">
                <h2>sub header 2-3</h2>
                <p>para 11</p>
                <p>para 12</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</doc>
```

To get above expected result, my xsl code is follows,

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group-list" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:if test="$elements[self::*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]]">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
        <li>
          <a href="#{local-name()}-{count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() eq local-name(current())]) + 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </a>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group-list(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ul>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:group-div" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
        <div id="{local-name()}-{count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() eq local-name(current())]) + 1}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group-div(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="doc">
  <xsl:copy>
    <div name="list">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group-list(h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6, 1)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group-div(*, 1)"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

above xslt works fine and it creates the unordered list I needed, however what I cannot do is add the attributes to the list items (css `class` and `id` to add styles as shown in the expected result).

I'm new to xslt and I tried to do this but unable to get the expected result. can anyone suggest a method to add those attributes to the result html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  <xsl:if test="$elements[self::*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]]">
    <ul>
      ...
```

to

```
  <xsl:if test="$elements[self::*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]]">
    <ul>
      <xsl:if test="$elements[self::h1]">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">menu</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      ...
```

If you want to add a `class` attribute to all `li` elements then change

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
    <li>
```

to

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
    <li class="{if (self::h1) then 'has-sub' else 'last'}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). second part is working fine but when adding id attribute to the <ul> (first part) it gives me an error - "Evaluation will always fail: there is no context item", any idea why it is not working?